# Install Metasploit under Cygwin?

Tags: linux, metasploit

Is there a way to install Metasploit under Cygwin? Metasploit is meant to be run under a linux environment.
The Windows installation doesn't have many tools such as msfpayload available.
Please contribute with an answer, not alternative methods.

Comment: Install a linux virtual instance to run it?

Comment: Why would you install a linux virtual instance if it runs natively Windows :P?

Comment: He mentioned that the Windows version is missing some features. I cannot verify this claim though. I think if the desired result was to run the linux version, he may have better luck with a VM instead of Cygwin.

Comment: @DavidHoude Thanks, finally somebody has noticed my point.

Answer (score 5):

> Metasploit is meant to be run under a linux environment.

Wrong. Metasploit is simply a collection of Ruby scripts, so all you need is Ruby installed. Also, Metasploit has a [Windows installer](http://www.rapid7.com/products/metasploit/download.jsp) so go crazy with it...

Comment: I'm aware of the of the windows installer but it doesn't have many tools such as msfpayload available.

Comment: then download virtual box and learn linux.  I know that sounds harsh but really that's probably the best route.  Linux is free and so is virtual box.

Comment: virtual system is extremely un-memory-efficient and uses too many resources to run metasploit. There are also always networking problems especially with virtual box which can't emulate NIC.

Answer (score 0):

No, or at least we don't know of a way to accomplish what you're asking as of now.
However, we do recommend that you install a virtual linux system and run metasploit that way.